# How can I use Material Components through object library/storyboard?

Tags: material-components-ios

I'd like to know if it's possible to use Material Components dragging them from my object library directly to the storyboard views.

Thanks,

Answer (score 10):

Yes, You can use storyboard objects for designing MaterialDesign Components.

For Example:

If you want to have a floating button in your app, then simply drag UIButton object in storyboard and change its class Name from UIButton to MDCFloatingButton as in the following image.

[image: Floating button]

Add set constraint, title and color as you wish.

The result in simulator will look like this -

[image: Simulator]

Hope this helps..!